# MIDDLEMAN: "$ middleman init my_new_project" not working (screenshot attached)

Tags: ruby, middleman

I just installed Ruby and Middleman for the first time and I cannot get past the very first "$ middleman init my_new_project" step. I have tried Googling for solution to my problem but unfortunately I couldn't find anything that looks like the error I'm encountering.

I hope someone can help me out.

OS: Windows 10 |
Ruby: 2.2.3 (x64) (tried Ruby 2.1.7 first) |
Middleman: 4.0.0

This is the error message I'm getting when I try to create a new project in a folder I created to try out Middleman:

```
    run git clone --depth 1 git://github.com/middleman/middleman-templates-default.git C:/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Local/Temp/d20160120-1612-c2sqbk from "."
    exist new_project_test
      run bundle install from ".new_project_test"
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

This just creates an empty "new_project_test" folder.

Screenshot of the command prompt: [middleman init not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt9uS.png) ([alt. image link](http://imageshack.com/a/img903/6940/JQBsMv.png))

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you just run 'middleman init'?

You can also try to create the Gemfile manually, if it's not getting created on the first step, then run init again. The default one would look like this:

```
# If you do not have OpenSSL installed, update
# the following line to use "http://" instead
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "middleman", "~>3.4.1"

# Live-reloading plugin
gem "middleman-livereload", "~> 3.3.0"

# For faster file watcher updates on Windows:
gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.0", :platforms => [:mswin, :mingw]

# Windows does not come with time zone data
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: [:mswin, :mingw, :jruby]
```